# Точки не отрисовываются, когда открываешь картинку через проводник. PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, рисование, paintevent

Когда кликаешь в пустое окно точки отрисовываются, 
а когда открываешь картинку через **`Файл -> Открыть`** и снова кликаешь точек нет.

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog, QAction, QWidget, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QCursor, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt

imagePath = ''
    
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    
        self.chosen_points = []
        self.zero = 0, 0
        self.scaleX = 0, 0
        self.ScaleY = 0, 0
    
        self.setWindowTitle('Оцифровка графиков')
    
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Редактор')
        self.resize(500, 500)
    
        openAction = QAction('Открыть', self)  
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O') 
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
    
        closeAction = QAction('Выход', self)  
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close) 
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
    
        editAction = QAction('Выбрать точки', self)  
        editAction.triggered.connect(self.choosePoint)
        editMenu.addAction(editAction)
    
    def openImage(self):
        global imagePath
        imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.size())
        self.adjustSize()
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        if mouse_event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.cursor = QCursor()
            #self.zero.append(mouse_event.pos())
            print(mouse_event.x(), mouse_event.y())
            self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())
            self.update()
            
    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)
            print(imagePath)
    
    def choosePoint(self):
        pass
        
    
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    return app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы когда загружаете новое изображение не дано ничего делать, 
а вы накрывали свой холст новым изображением.

Ну и глобальные переменные - это зло.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog, 
                             QAction, QWidget, QGraphicsItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QCursor, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt

#imagePath = ''

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.imagePath = ''          # 'Ok.png'

        self.chosen_points = []
        self.zero   = (0,0)
        self.scaleX = (0,0)
        self.ScaleY = (0,0)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Редактор')
        self.resize(500, 500)
        openAction = QAction('Открыть', self)  
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O') 
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        closeAction = QAction('Выход', self)  
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close) 
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
        editAction = QAction('Выбрать точки', self)  
        editAction.triggered.connect(self.choosePoint)
        editMenu.addAction(editAction)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

    def openImage(self):
#        global imagePath
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "", 
                                                        "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
        """  не надо этого делать !                                              
        if self.imagePath:
            pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.resize(pixmap.size())
            self.adjustSize()
        """ 

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        if mouse_event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.cursor = QCursor()
            #self.zero.append(mouse_event.pos())
#            print(mouse_event.x(), mouse_event.y())
            self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QPainter(self)               
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)
        pen = QPen(QColor("green"))
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)
#            print(self.imagePath)

    def choosePoint(self):
        print("def choosePoint(self):")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.setWindowTitle('Оцифровка графиков')
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хороший у вас пример, предлагаю немного отрефакторить -- перенести загрузку картинки из файла в функцию открытия файла. Т.е. в конструкторе завести поле: `self.pixmap = QPixmap()`, в `openImage` добавить `self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)`, а в `paintEvent` убрать загрузку `pixmap` и добавить `painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pixmap)`

Answer (score 0):

Переписал код, сделав специальный виджет для рисования точек и отображения на фоне картинки из файлах.

Изначально писал подобный код на MainWindow, но возникли проблемы с расположением точек относительно главного окна и label'а, на чей pixmap рисовали, плюс понадобились костыли -- создание копии pixmap'а, рисование на копии, помещение копии в `label` (были и другие проблемы).

Поэтому, решил сделать правильно.

Вот попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize


class Canvas(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.source_pixmap = None
        self.chosen_points = []

    def load(self, file_name: str):
        self.source_pixmap = QPixmap(file_name)

        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.source_pixmap:
            return self.source_pixmap.size()

        return QSize(100, 100)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        if mouse_event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        if self.source_pixmap:
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.source_pixmap)

            # Если нужно, чтобы картинка была растянута
            # painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.source_pixmap)

        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)

        painter.end()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.imagePath = ''

        self.setWindowTitle('Оцифровка графиков')

        self.canvas = Canvas()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Редактор')

        openAction = fileMenu.addAction('Открыть')
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage)

        closeAction = fileMenu.addAction('Выход')
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        editAction = editMenu.addAction('Выбрать точки')
        editAction.triggered.connect(self.choosePoint)

    def openImage(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if not self.imagePath:
            return

        self.canvas.load(self.imagePath)
        self.resize(self.canvas.size())
        self.adjustSize()

    def choosePoint(self):
        pass


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.resize(500, 500)
    win.show()
    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

**PS.**

Делал простой paint, можете там посмотреть пример реализации рисования: https://github.com/gil9red/fake-painter