# Как сделать отображение картинки не на всё окно, а в ограниченной области? PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

И как можно разграничить область с картинкой и область с radiobutton? При этом нужно сохранить пропорции картинки в области. Код на Python.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog, 
                         QAction, QWidget, QGraphicsItem, QRadioButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QCursor, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QRect

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.imagePath = ''          
        self.chosen_points = []
        self.zeroX   = 0
        self.zeroY   = 0

        self.scaleX_x = 0
        self.scaleX_y = 0

        self.scaleY_x = 0
        self.scaleY_y = 0

        self.chooseColor = 0

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Редактор')
        openAction = QAction('Открыть', self)  
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O') 
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        closeAction = QAction('Выход', self)  
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close) 
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
        editAction = QAction('Выбрать точки', self)  
        editAction.triggered.connect(self.choosePoint)
        editMenu.addAction(editAction)

        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.rB1 = QRadioButton("Отметить точку (0, 0)", self)
        self.rB1.setGeometry(QRect(600, 20, 900, 17))
        self.rB1.setChecked(True)  
        self.rB2 = QRadioButton("Отметить точку (1, 0)", self)
        self.rB2.setGeometry(QRect(600, 40, 900, 17))
        self.rB3 = QRadioButton("Отметить точку (0, 1)", self)
        self.rB3.setGeometry(QRect(600, 60, 900, 17))
        self.rB4 = QRadioButton("Отметить точки на графике", self)
        self.rB4.setGeometry(QRect(600, 80, 900, 17))

    def openImage(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        self.cursor = QCursor()

        if mouse_event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            if self.rB1.isChecked() == True:
                self.zeroX = mouse_event.x()
                self.zeroY = mouse_event.y()
                print(self.zeroX, self.zeroY)
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())


            if self.rB2.isChecked() == True:
                self.scaleX_x = mouse_event.x()
                self.scaleX_y = mouse_event.y()
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())

            if self.rB3.isChecked() == True:
                self.scaleY_x = mouse_event.x()
                self.scaleY_y = mouse_event.y()
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())

            if self.rB4.isChecked() == True:
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QPainter(self)               
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap)
        if self.imagePath:
            self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        pen = QPen(QColor("green"))
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)

    def choosePoint(self):
        print("def choosePoint(self):")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.setWindowTitle('Оцифровка графиков')
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> И как можно разграничить область с картинкой и область с radiobutton?

В текущем виде самое простое -- захаркодить ширину картинки. А по хорошему сделать виджет для картинки (в вашем предыдущем вопросе я оставлял [ответ с таким виджетом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1051518/201445)) и через компоновщики (layout'ы) разместить виджет и кнопки.

> При этом нужно сохранить пропорции картинки в области

Делайте у pixmap перед рисование вызов scaled туда передавайте ширину, высоту и способ Qt.KeepAspectRatio, тогда картинка сохранит пропорции. И рисуйте так:

```
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)
```

---

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog,
                         QAction, QWidget, QGraphicsItem, QRadioButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QCursor, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QRect

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.imagePath = ''
        self.chosen_points = []
        self.zeroX   = 0
        self.zeroY   = 0

        self.scaleX_x = 0
        self.scaleX_y = 0

        self.scaleY_x = 0
        self.scaleY_y = 0

        self._fixed_image_width = 500  # Добавил ширину

        self.chooseColor = 0

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        editMenu = menubar.addMenu('Редактор')
        openAction = QAction('Открыть', self)
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        closeAction = QAction('Выход', self)
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)
        editAction = QAction('Выбрать точки', self)
        editAction.triggered.connect(self.choosePoint)
        editMenu.addAction(editAction)

        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.rB1 = QRadioButton("Отметить точку (0, 0)", self)
        self.rB1.setGeometry(QRect(600, 20, 900, 17))
        self.rB1.setChecked(True)
        self.rB2 = QRadioButton("Отметить точку (1, 0)", self)
        self.rB2.setGeometry(QRect(600, 40, 900, 17))
        self.rB3 = QRadioButton("Отметить точку (0, 1)", self)
        self.rB3.setGeometry(QRect(600, 60, 900, 17))
        self.rB4 = QRadioButton("Отметить точки на графике", self)
        self.rB4.setGeometry(QRect(600, 80, 900, 17))

    def openImage(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        self.cursor = QCursor()

        if mouse_event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            if self.rB1.isChecked() == True:
                self.zeroX = mouse_event.x()
                self.zeroY = mouse_event.y()
                print(self.zeroX, self.zeroY)
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())


            if self.rB2.isChecked() == True:
                self.scaleX_x = mouse_event.x()
                self.scaleX_y = mouse_event.y()
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())

            if self.rB3.isChecked() == True:
                self.scaleY_x = mouse_event.x()
                self.scaleY_y = mouse_event.y()
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())

            if self.rB4.isChecked() == True:
                self.chosen_points.append(mouse_event.pos())
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        if self.imagePath:
            w, h = self._fixed_image_width, self.height()  # Берем нашу ширину и высоту виджета

            pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(w, h, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)  # Маштабируем картинку с сохранением пропорций
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap)  # Рисуем картинку начиная с левого верхнего угла
            # self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        pen = QPen(QColor("green"))
        pen.setWidth(5)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)

    def choosePoint(self):
        print("def choosePoint(self):")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.setWindowTitle('Оцифровка графиков')
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**PS.**

Вместо

```
w, h = self._fixed_image_width, self.height()
```

можно брать, например, половину текущей ширины окна:

```
w, h = self.width() // 2, self.height()
```